# Python Call function within a function and reset one of the argument

Tags: python, function

I want to call a Python function y within another function x by passing on the arguments for function y, and then dynamically reset one of the parameters of function y during execution. How can I do it? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
def functiony(p,q,r):
    return (p+q)*r

def functionx(functiony,loopvalue):
    for i in loopvalue:
        <<code to reset the 'r' argument of function y, keeping other arguments the same>>
        print(functiony)

functionx(functiony(2,3,4),loopvalue=[10,20,30])
```

Comment: I'm confused on why the code you posted doesn't work out for you?

Comment: This might be a so-called "XY problem", don't fall for that. Anyway, it's not clear to me what you want or how you want the code to behave, but it seems as if you wanted something like currying or function composition.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `functiony` into `functionx`, just pass `functiony`'s args into `functionx`

```
def functiony(p,q,r):
    return (p+q)*r

def functionx(functiony_args,loopvalue):
    for i in loopvalue:
        functiony_args[1] = i
        print(functiony(*functiony_args))

functionx([2,3,4],loopvalue=[10,20,30])
```

Comment: Hi,Is there a way to specify argument by referring to its name rather than the index?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Pass on the arguments as a dictionary and use ** instead of * while passing arguments.